# How do I test my SQL server connection?

Tags: java, sql-server, android-studio, jdbc, azure-sql-database

I have the following code for a login page.

I created the following to get data entered in box that receives credentials.

```
final String NameHere = HeldUser.getText().toString();
    final String PasswordHere = HeldPasssword.getText().toString();
```

The following is my query where they are compared to what I have in my database.

```
ArryList<String> names= null;
ArrayList<String> password = null;
try{ 
con = MyConnectionClass(); 
String query = null;
if(con == null){
z = "Check Your Internet Access!"; 
                 // I have a toast RIGHT HERE to that I figured would trigger
                    the connection was not successful.. 
                Toast.makeText(Async.this, "Connection failures. Contact Administrator.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} else { 
if (Condition that I know is being triggered){
MyQueryDeclaredEarlier = "select * from MyTable where Username = '"+NameHere+ "'and Password = '"+PasswordHere+"'";
//     The above was written with the +NameHere+ and +PasswordHere+ variables 
         receive String from EditTextBoxes I have for gathering credentials 

//     The Columns (Username and Password) are correct and the tablename (Table) 
       is also, as is, in the SQL management database. (I exluded dbo.) 

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(MyQueryDeclaredEarlier); 

while (rs.next()){
names.add(0,rs.getString("Username"));
password.add(0,rs.getString("Password"));
}
// then I just compare the username variable (NameHere) contents to 
// the string I got from the ResultSet (rs) and added to the ListArray (names)
at position 0. 
// I think this where the problem is. 
String FromQuery = names.get(0).toString();
if(NameHere.equals(FromQuery)){
z = "query successful"
isSuccess = true;
}
else{ 
z = "Invalid Query!"; 
isSuccess = false; 
}
```

Imma leave out the rest of the '}'s

It keeps returning isSuccess as false.

Is their any easy way to test the actual connection? 
I've got two modules attached to this project. The appropriate dependencies are included but I'm not sure if theirs nothing else that is going on I can't see or that Android can't read for me. Help.

Comment: it's obvious that `NameHere.equals(FromQuery)` is not evaluating to true. Why not debug it to see what value you are getting back?  Or, is it possible to do any logging?

Comment: I actually figured something different out. Appreciate the advice though! I'm struggling with getting the sql driver to integrate, as of now. Probably about to post a new question. Got hit it for a little bit and see where I can get. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't answer your question with "FIXED!!!!". Instead, formulate a good answer explaining your steps to solve this problem, so that future readers may learn something / receive the help they're looking for. =)

Comment: I just didn't want to clutter the site with unsolved question. I figured spamming myself wasn't malicious if my intention was to simply move the question to resolved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. I created a list Array and finalized it at the beginning. Instead of playing with the boolean values (which was the actual problem), I validated in the postExecute with String passed from DoinBAckground method. Still have not been able to confirm whether the String Variable that takes characters from the textbox and the String gathered from the query match because I'm having problems with the mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.java driver. Had as a module but that seems not to be working. Putting it into library and setting the dependency as compile file: libs/drivername rather than using a compile project: drivername

Not sure if this will work but I need to get testing soon. If I need any more help I'll pose a new question but I think I can get this part alone.